# Vim nth column even if it doesn't exist

Tags: vim

Let's say I have 20 columns in the line. I want to go to 30th column in vim and I want everything after 20th column to be spaces. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You run on that line, from normal mode:

```
$10a<space><esc>
```

If you have to do this often, you can use `:set virtualedit=all` (at least while you need it) in order to be able to move your cursor past the end of the line and insert text in any column you want.